Dynamic measurement of PivotTable height and width (no VBA)
How can a PivotTable's height and width be measured dynamically without using VBA (i.e., Even when the PivotTable is modified with slicers or through changes in the Field List)? With 'height' being the number of rows the PivotTable spans and 'width' being the corresponding column amount.

With a structured Table in Excel, one can just reference the name of
the Table inside a ROWS() or COLUMNS() -formula to get the dynamic
height and width, but is there a comprable way for PivotTables?

Non-robust solution: Use COUNTA() to get the number of non-empty cells in the first column and second row of the PivotTable (Prone to errors; Non-empty data outside the PivotTable or empty data inside the PivotTable).

Did you try pt.TableRange2.Rows.Count and pt.TableRange2.Columns.Count

VBA solutions aren't preferable. I updated the question accordingly.

IMHO then there is no way an excel formula can help you with this. TableRange2 takes into account the blank cells of the PT and this AFAIK cannot be used in an Excel formula.

That's probably true. I just want to see if this is solvable without VBA - you never know.

GETPIVOTDATA is really the only pivot table specific function, and that won't help here, so I think the answer is no.
